# Evaluate the following definite integral?

Tags: integration

How to evaluate the following integral?
[image: definite integral]

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that the solution cannot express in terms of elementary functions.

Just for your curiosity,
$$\int\log(1+e^x)\,dx=-\text{Li}_2\left(-e^x\right)$$ where appears the  polylogarithm function which is defined by $$\text{Li}_n(z)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {z^k}{k^n}$$ So $$I(a)=\int_{-a}^{+a}\log(1+e^x)\,dx=\text{Li}_2\left(-e^{-a}\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(-e^a\right)$$ The result is a very smooth function which, at least for "small" values of $a$ can be expanded as a Taylor series built around $a=0$ $$I(a)=2 a \log (2)+\frac{a^3}{12}-\frac{a^5}{480}+\frac{a^7}{10080}+O\left(a^8\right)$$ For example, if $a=1$, the exact value would be $\approx 1.467638074$ while the above approximation would give $\approx 1.4676435670$.

For large values of $a$, the approximation is $$I(a)=\frac{a^2}{2}+\frac{\pi
   ^2}{6}-2 e^{-a}+\frac{1}{2}e^{-2 a}+\cdots$$

Comment: it is a very nice effort. If this integral can not be express in terms of elementary function then can we expand the logarithm in power series and integrate term by term? can any one will try for me? i will be very much obliged.

Comment: I agree with Claude , we better approximate it.